# Changing image URLs in media library

Tags: plugins, filters, uploads, media-library, cdn

On a default wordpress install, the media library is located at:
`/wp-admin/upload.php`. I am trying to update the image URL to point to my CDN, not my local server.

This filter

```
add_filter('admin_post_thumbnail_html', 'my-function', 1000, 5);
```

will update the featured image URLs in the admin, but not the images in the media library list table. Is there a filter or action I am missing?

Comment: The easiest solution I can think of would be to use the W3 Total Cache plugin. It has an excellent implementation of CDNs... I hope that helps!

Comment: I second what @WPMU-DEVAri said. Use W3 Total Cache and set up a CDN. That way you're not hard-coding changes to your site's structure that, if you ever decide to change them, will mean lots of changes and extra work. Just let the plugin handle that for you.